# how I generate 1000 rps in Jmeter

Tags: api, testing, curl, jmeter, load

I have to perform CURl API load testing on Jmeter,
requirements are:
The api will be ingesting usage event apis from multiple businesses at the same time. One business could be sending in 500 each second and there could be multiple businesses using this API.

Therefore I would like a full load test of this, specifically if it can sustain 1000 rps and what the performance for the API looks like.

what setting should I set for this on Jmeter?
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is not a job for the curl cli program. sounds like a job for the curl_multi api, or perhaps apache bench?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for each API endpoing you want to test
2. It might be the case you will also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) to send at least [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header
3. Set up the [workload model](https://www.innominds.com/blog/performance-test-workload-modelling-based-on-real-world-usage) reflecting anticipated real life usage of your API by either putting the relevant requests under different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or using Throughput Controllers
4. Kick off a [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) by starting with 1 user and gradually increase the load until you reach 1000 RPS or response time starts increasing or errors start occurring or application dies, whatever comes the first.

Comment: I have done all work, jut need to know how to set 1000  RPS?